# Parse JSON with dynamic key object inside dynamic key object with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am a newbie to android and I have a JSON file with dynamic key like this:

```
{
  "x": {
    "a": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    },
    "b": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    }
  },
  "y": {
    "a": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    },
    "b": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    }
  },
  "z": {
    "a": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    },
    "b": {
      "1": [1,2,3,4],
      "2": [1,2,3,4]
    }
  }
}
```

I parsed it successfully by JSONObject but I have to loop by keys Iterator on x, y, z. For each time, I have to loop on a, b and the same for "1" and "2". I think it's not a good solution. I created models for them like this:

```
Class XYZ {
private String name; // "x", "y", "z" value
private ArrayList<ABC> abcList;
}

Class ABC {
private String name; // "a", "b", "c"
private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
}

Class Item{
private String ID; // "1", "2"
private int[] valueArray;
}
```

Can anyone help me to parse this json by Gson, I think it looks more professional :D. Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, provide relevant code for proving how far did you try and let other members where is you specific problem.

Comment: If keys dynamic the best choice I think convert to map. Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> myMap = gson.fromJson(jsonStringHere, type); And finally iterate over map key/values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Your JSON doesn't have `"name"` or `"ID"`key, so that Java model isn't correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models cannot map your JSON just because Gson default configuration clearly gets them unmatched.

You can have two "default" ways:

#### static

... since you didn't really mention *why* your JSON is considered dynamic:

```java
final class XYZ {

    final ABC x = null;
    final ABC y = null;
    final ABC z = null;

}
```

```java
final class ABC {

    final OneTwo a = null;
    final OneTwo b = null;

}
```

```java
final class OneTwo {

    @SerializedName("1")
    final List<Integer> one = null;

    @SerializedName("2")
    final List<Integer> two = null;

}
```

Example:

```java
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43695739.class, "dynamic.json") ) {
    final XYZ xyz = gson.fromJson(reader, XYZ.class);
    System.out.println(xyz.x.b.two);
}
```

#### dynamic (by deserialization)

... assuming your keys are dynamic, but the structure remains the same:

```java
private static final Type stringToStringToStringToIntegerListType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>>>() {
}.getType();
```

```java
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43695739.class, "dynamic.json") ) {
    final Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>> m = gson.fromJson(reader, stringToStringToStringToIntegerListType);
    System.out.println(m.get("x").get("b").get("2"));
}
```

#### dynamic (by JSON trees)

Another true dynamic approach that may be helpful for some scenarios. Also note that `JSONObject` is not in the Gson realm: you probably might have imported this one from the `org.json` package. Gson uses camel-cased names like `JsonElement`, `JsonObject`, etc.

```java
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43695739.class, "dynamic.json") ) {
    final JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class)
            .getAsJsonObject()
            .getAsJsonObject("x")
            .getAsJsonObject("b")
            .getAsJsonArray("2");
    System.out.println(jsonElement);
}
```

The first and the second examples produce `java.util.List` instances

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

The third example returns a `JsonArray` instance with a slightly different `toString` implementation:

> [1,2,3,4]